# How can I put each item of a list into a particular format?

Tags: python, list, split, format

Here is my list.

```
output_list=['Jenny\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n2021/3/4\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n       300\n\n\n\n\n\n      \n\n\n\n\n\n',
             'Cindy\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n2022/4/5\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n       700\n\n\n\n\n\n      \n\n\n\n\n\n',
             'Kevin\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n2011/5/8\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n       210\n\n\n\n\n\n      \n\n\n\n\n\n']
```

I've been trying to put each item into this format directly.

```
Name: Jenny, Date: 2021/3/4, Like: 300
Name: Cindy, Date: 2022/4/5, Like: 700
Name: Kevin, Date: 2011/5/8, Like: 210
```

I've been trying several ways but they didn't work. If anyone knows any way to do it, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split on 1 or more whitespace chars, and strip possible leading and trailing newlines.

```
import re

output_list=['Jenny\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n2021/3/4\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n       300\n\n\n\n\n\n      \n\n\n\n\n\n',
             'Cindy\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n2022/4/5\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n       700\n\n\n\n\n\n      \n\n\n\n\n\n',
             'Kevin\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n2011/5/8\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n       210\n\n\n\n\n\n      \n\n\n\n\n\n']

for item in output_list:
    res = re.split(r"\s+", item.strip())
    print(f"Name: {res[0]}, Date: {res[1]}, Like: {res[2]}")
```

Output

```
Name: Jenny, Date: 2021/3/4, Like: 300
Name: Cindy, Date: 2022/4/5, Like: 700
Name: Kevin, Date: 2011/5/8, Like: 210
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/RHV02B)

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
putput_list=['Jenny\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n2021/3/4\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n       300\n\n\n\n\n\n      \n\n\n\n\n\n',
             'Cindy\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n2022/4/5\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n       700\n\n\n\n\n\n      \n\n\n\n\n\n',
             'Kevin\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n2011/5/8\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n       210\n\n\n\n\n\n      \n\n\n\n\n\n']

newlist = []

for i in range(len(output_list)):
    output_list[i] = output_list[i].replace(' ','')
    output_list[i] = output_list[i].split('\n')
    
    if i != '':
        newlist.append(i)
for i in range(len(newlist)):
    print('Name: {}, Date: {}, Like: {}'.format(newlist[0],newlist[1],newlist[2]))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me. However, it kept showing the error of `'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`. If you know where the bug is, please help me solve it.

Comment: Did you call your list `list` ?

Comment: I changed my code, it should work now, replace and split just work on strings and not lists, I didn't saw my mistake sorry ^^